# Combine CSS background lineal gradient

Tags: css, background, background-image, linear-gradients

How can I combine this line, in two separate classes css?

```
background: url('image1.png') center 50% no-repeat, url('image2.png') 100% 100% no-repeat, linear-gradient(#000000, #ffffff);
```

Especially I need a different css class for **linear-gradient**

Something like...

```
.a {
   background-image: url('image1.png');
   background-position: center 50%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-image: url('image2.png');
   background-position: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.b {
   background-image: linear-gradient(#000000, #ffffff);
}

<div class="a b"></div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on CSS variable and do something like this:

```css
:root {
 /* The default gradient is transparent */
 --c:linear-gradient(transparent,transparent)
}

.a,.c {
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-image:var(--c),url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
  background-size:auto,cover;
}

.c {
  background-image:
  radial-gradient(circle at center,pink 20%,transparent 30%),
  var(--c),
  url(https://lorempixel.com/400/400/);
}
.b {
 --c:linear-gradient(red,transparent)
}
.d {
 --c:linear-gradient(to right,blue,transparent)
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
</div>

<div class="a b">
</div>

<div class="c d">
</div>

<div class="a d">
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Another idea is to use the *old* pseudo-element trick but this will work only if the gradient should be on the top or bottom layer:

```css
.a,.c {
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-image:url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
  background-size:cover;
}

.c {
  background-image:url(https://lorempixel.com/400/400/);
}
.b,.d {
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.b:before,.d:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:1;
  background:linear-gradient(red,transparent);
}
.d:before {
 background:linear-gradient(to right,blue,transparent);
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
</div>

<div class="a b">
</div>

<div class="c d">
</div>

<div class="a d">
</div>
```

Comment: I need only ONE DIV. I use a PNG for shadow and the other one is the image.

Comment: @FeKuLa i simply provided many cases to show my idea ;) then you can keep it only one div .. the same logic will apply, the idea is to have the gradient always there using variables and update it with the second class

Comment: There are not support for IE using CSS variables :-(

Comment: @FeKuLa ah, if you are looking for IE :) ok i added another way then ;) ... but you should try to forget IE :p